# Have CMake not complain about non-existant file?

Tags: cmake

I know there probably isn't any workaround to this, but I need to generate a source file `dllmain.c` for my model.dll. This is done together with an executable that extracts some essential information for me, so my current `CMakeLists` looks like this

```
add_executable(main ${SOURCE} otherListSourcesGoHere)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET main
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND main.exe <--- Main built from above
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/jtox.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/dllgen.py <--- Python script generating a 
                                                       sourcefile for my DLL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_DIR}/build/dllmain.c ${PROJECT_DIR}
)

add_library(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${PROJECT_DIR}/dllmain.c
    otherListSoucrsGoHereAswell
)
```

But of course, as the dllmain.c file is non-existant before the exe has been completed and ran, I can't use this as it will return an error. Is is possible to execute this somehow without having to run two CMakeLists?

**EDIT 1**
With the help of @Angew I found out that you could specify the output of a file in a add_custom_command, so currently I have this instead

```
add_executable(main ${SOURCE} otherListSourcesGoHere)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
    COMMAND main
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/jtox.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/dllgen.py -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
)

add_library(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
    otherListSoucrsGoHereAswell
)
```

But I have the error

```
CMakeFiles\bil.dir\build.make:60: recipe for target '../dllmain.c' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bil.dir/all' failed
makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I don't seem to find a solution. How can I go about debugging this issue?

**EDIT 2**

I fixed this issue by adding DEPENDS main on add_custom_command

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PROJECT_DIR}/dllmain.c
    DEPENDS main
    COMMAND echo "Executing main.exe"
    COMMAND main.exe
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND echo "JSON to XML with Python"
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/jtox.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/dllgen.py -o ${PROJECT_DIR}
```

)

Comment: What is the reason for the `sleep`s? Usually, reuquiring a `sleep` is an indication of bad design somewhere.

Comment: @Angew Haven't actually tested it without, but I was afraid the file(s) generated from my executables and python scripts wouldn't be available fast enough and cause crashes. I would probably implement a timeout check to the python scripts instead but I haven't come around to do it yet.

Comment: If such sleeps were needed, 99% of all CMake projects out there in the wild would be broken. Unless you're doing *really* weird stuff in `main` or the Python scripts, you can safely leave the sleeps out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to tell CMake how to generate the file instead of doing it "manually" and keeping it secret from CMake. To do this, change your CMakeList like this:

```
add_executable(main ${SOURCE} otherListSourcesGoHere)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PROJECT_DIR}/dllmain.c
    COMMAND main
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/jtox.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/dllgen.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_DIR}/build/dllmain.c ${PROJECT_DIR}
)

add_library(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${PROJECT_DIR}/dllmain.c
    otherListSoucrsGoHereAswell
)
```

This way, CMake will know that the file `${PROJECT_DIR}/dllmain.c` is generated, and also how to generate it. It will correctly replace `main` with the executable built from target `main`, and introdce a proper build depencency.

---

Side note: you should consider modifying `dllgen.py` so that it's able to generate a file in a directory of your choice, and have it generate into the binary directory. That way, you will not pollute your source tree with build artefacts, which is a very desirable property: it allows you to revert to pristine state just by removing the binary dir. With that change, the CMakeList could look like this:

```
add_executable(main ${SOURCE} otherListSourcesGoHere)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
    COMMAND main
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/jtox.py
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E sleep 1
    COMMAND python ${PYTHON_SOURCE_DIR}/dllgen.py -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
)

add_library(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/dllmain.c
    otherListSoucrsGoHereAswell
)
```

Comment: OH I completely put that out of my mind after reading the documentation of `add_custom_command`. Didn't think I would need it, but here I am. Thanks for the tip about adding the path arg on dllgen.py! Will do. :)

Comment: Hey, I'm having some other issues with the updates CMakeLists.txt. I have never had these errors before so I was wondering if there is somehow a way to debug them? Updated my question with the errors

Comment: @Kvixen Well, "recipe for X failed" means that X failed to build. Since `dllmain.c` is built by your Python script, you will have to study its error output/debug it to find out what the problem is.